# What are the differences between Stratamed and Strataderm gels?

Tags: dermatology, scar-tissue-scars, plastic-surgery

Recently some man had injured my eyes and eyelid skin. My lower eyelid skin was ripped. Lacrimal channel was ripped as well. In the hospital, my wound on the inferior eyelid was stitched. A week ago the stitches were removed.

I want to contribute to the skin to prevent excessive formation of scar tissue.

---

Which is more suitable for the treatment of fresh scar? **Stratamed** gel or **Strataderm**. Or is there no difference?

Comment: I'm not sure if there have been quality studies or unbiased professional evaluation of either of those, so I don't know if they are actually safe or effective at all in the first place.  But at a glance the -med states it is designed for use when the wound is still open, and the -derm only after it has healed.  There is definitely overlap in there, however.

Unless this is a more common item than I'm familiar with, you might find a better answer asking them directly on their website, or a dermatology site.